# Custom object based on database table

Tags: php, oracle

Suppose that I have a database query which looks like below -

```
select name, gender, birthday from person where person_id = 1;
```

When this query is executed, some records from the database is returned. I want to execute this query inside a function, then make a custom object which will contain the exact attributes as the column names, with the corresponding values. As an example, suppose that the object is **X**. So it will have three attributes which are **X->name**, **X->gender** and **X->birthday**, with the corresponding values from the records.

As a second example, consider the following query -

```
select test1, test2, test3 from test where test_id = 1;
```

I want to execute this query inside the same function and using the same method, then generate a custom-object **Y** which will contain the attributes **Y->test1**, **Y->test2** and **Y->test3**.

Is it doable in PHP? If so, then how?

Edit: By custom object, I meant any kind of object. It does not need to be an instance of a specific class or something like that. I just want to return an object from that function so that I can populate the appropriate classes from the returned object's property values.

Comment: No idea how to do oracle, but I'd start here: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-oci.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:** this answer assumed Archangel used MySQL, which it turns out is not the case. Sorry for the mistake! I'll leave my answer here in case any MySQL folks come across it, as well as to preserve the comments if necessary.

If you don't care about custom classes and only want your custom attribute names in the row objects, this is all you need:

```
$row_object = mysql_fetch_object($result);
```

Otherwise, you'll need to write your own class yourself (I'm not sure whether a constructor is needed or the function populates your object with data automatically):

```
class X
{
    public $name;
    public $gender;
    public $birthday;
}
```

Then call the function like this:

```
$row_object = mysql_fetch_object($result, 'X');
```

There's no built-in way that I know of to generate classes on-the-fly for you; you'll have to write your own classes.

Comment: what about Oracle? what should I do if I want to fetch the object from an Oracle database ?

Comment: Ah, you didn't say so. I've never worked with Oracle though, so unfortunately I can't answer your question. I'll retag your question so it's clear which database you're using.

Comment: Thanks dev-null-dweller. Another thing to note: I checked the PHP manual and while `oci_fetch_object()` works, it doesn't allow the programmer to use custom classes with it.

Comment: @dev-null-dweller: Archangel has just made it clear he just wants the right attributes. I don't want to steal reputation from you, so you should probably post your answer ;)

Comment: There's no need since I missed custom object part, so @Svisstack answer is more correct

Answer (score 3):

```
foreach ($result as $key => $value)
{
    $your_object->{$key} = $value;
}
```

Comment: First part is OK, but second is heresy! Concatenation will try to cast object to string

Comment: You can also delete your answer. But what's wrong with the first option?